# Check if user input was already inputted

Tags: c#, if-statement, console-application

Im trying to make a user enter a char and check if they entered that char before. and if that happens ask him to enter another char that he hasn't used before. My knowledge is limited to if statements and loops so I would appreciate it if the solution is something that i can understand.

When i enter any letter e.g E it would throw it into the guessed array, if i enter E again, it throws into the guessed array again instead of asking the user to change the letter.

```
string check= "";
char wguess ='';
char[] wguess = new char[26];
do
{
    check = Console.ReadLine();

    if (check!="")
    {
        wguess = char.ToUpper(Convert.ToChar(check));
        for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
        {
            if (wguess == guessed[i])
            {
                Console.Write(wguess);
                Console.WriteLine(guessed[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose a letter you haven't used yet.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(wguess);
                Console.WriteLine(guessed[i]);
                temp = wguess;
                guessed[i] = wguess;
                wguess = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a letter.");
    }
} while (check=="");
```

> Output1 = Guessed Letters: E
>
> Output2 = Guessed Letters: EE

Comment: You need an if statement, and some type of variable that can store a *list* of what the user has already entered.

Comment: You may want to use `ReadKey()` instead, because `ReadLine()` returns a string, which may be 1 or 100 characters (you should only take the first one). Then you can store those characters in a `char[]` or even in a `string`, and then use `Contains` (requires including the `Linq` namespace) or `IndexOf` respectively to check if it's there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Contains method, like this:

```
  If(guessed.Contains(wguess)
    { 
       //Whatever happens when the character already has been entered
    }
    else
    {
      //Whatever happens when the character has not been guessed
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped tons. had to experiment a bit but it ended up working in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like the following:

```
do{
    check = char.ToUpper(Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey()));
    if (!guessed.Contains(check))
    {
        // This is new, not in the guessed
    }
    else 
    { 
    // Already entered
    }

} while (check==' ');
```